# How do I update a JSON column with a NULL value?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Hi Im trying to add / update data in my json column - where the value inside is NULL
not having much luck - here is my query that errors

```
update departments 
set (data->>'formal_name') = departments.name 
where (data->>'formal_name') is null
```

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using some Alpha release of PostgreSQL 9.5 you cannot update the data inside a JSON column:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#JSONB-modifying_operators_and_functions

Also, consider the advice given in this answer:

[How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb)

And if you really need to modify the data in the JSON field, you will probably have to decompose the JSON with json_array_elements() and then build it again as a whole, as explained here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array