# Json type column element update - Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4

I have a issue on updating json type column element value;

```
UPDATE employer SET address->>'locality' = 'NYC' where "Id"='30'
```

address is jsonb type column and have following elements

```
{"region": "", "locality": "", "postal-code": "", "country-name": "CAN", "street-address": ""}
```

So how can I update locality element in this address column ?

Note ; Im using postgres 9.4

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4

Answer (score 0):

There is no option for me to update jsonB element. I need to update whole jsonb object.

Thanks