# Storing foreign keys in postgresql jsonb a bad idea?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

What are the problems associated with storing foreign keys in a jsonb column?

*Context:*

I have a table of items:

```
Item 
--------------------------
| id   | name | property |
| PK   | text |  jsonb   |
```

The property column is one-level jsonb of the following structure:

```
[
  {"value": "white", "item_attribute_id": "1"},
  {"value": "71", "item_attribute_id": "3"},
  {"value": "29", "item_attribute_id": "4"},
  {"value": "48-70", "item_attribute_id": "5"},
  {"value": "190", "item_attribute_id": "6"}
]
```

The item_attribute_id is a foreign key pointing to a table of attributes, which holds everything related to the given attribute (name, type, description).

I cannot find any literature on why this might be a good/bad practice. Are there any obvious directly related problems that I overlooked?

Comment: How would you select the names, types and description for all attributes for an Item?

Comment: I have tried to find some way, but it seems to me that I would need to leverage my ORM to do so (I use ActiveRecord, which supports the jsonb columns). Did you have something in mind?

Comment: Indeed - you'd need the ORM and the queries would become more complex than say `SELECT * FROM item_attributes LEFT JOIN attributes USING(attribute_id) WHERE item_id = ?`. Generally, I wouldn't use JSON or any other text/binary based complex content to store information that references the DB itself, but use proper FK's so the db will enforce them. I've had enough trouble with a MysqlDB that has a column storing foreign keys as `\0` separated values... But if it works for you, is well supported, fast, and the queries don't become unnecessarily complex, why not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take into consideration following things about [**`JSONB`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) type:

- **queries will be more complex**; if you even feel comfortable with all [**JSONB functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) (they are more about `SELECT` statements),  `UPDATE` operation will still be tricky - please consider **[@Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26704636/3961156)** regarding this.
- **size overhead;** for small docs it will not really matter, but at scale you might hit a wall. Just compare `pg_column_size()` results for your case.
- **limited indexing support**; you will have no luck when you perform search in `array` by `element` (functions like `json_array_elements()` etc).  Default `GIN` index supports queries with the (`CONTAINS`) `@>`, (`EXISTS`)`?`, (`EXISTS ALL`)`?&` and (`EXISTS ANY`)`?|` operators, so you need to be careful with the queries you are using. `jsonb` supports `btree` and `hash` indexes. You can check details [**here**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html).

Articles to consider:

- **[Rethinking JSONB from PGConf 2015](https://www.pgcon.org/2015/schedule/track/Hacking/784.en.html)**
- **[JSONB type performance in PostgreSQL 9.4](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/jsonb-type-performance-postgresql-9-4/)**

Comment: Thank you very much! I believe I can cope with all of these

1. update will be rare on those columns
2. ok this one i don't know, but i presuppose a few dozen attributes in that jsonb at maximum
3. no arrays should be there