# how to modify an array jsonb in postgresql?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, set, jsonb

In postgresql,I have a table which defined like this:

```
create table carts(
    id serial,
    cart json
)
```

has data like this:

```
id     cart
3      [{"productid":5,"cnt":6},{"productid":8,"cnt":1}]
5      [{"productid":2},{"productid":7,"cnt":1},{"productid":34,"cnt":3}]
```

if i want to modify the data "cnt", with id=n and productid=m,
how can I do this?
for example, when id=3,and productid=8, i want to change the cnt to cnt+3, 
how to realize it?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4) will help.

Comment: great question ,no one answer?

Comment: I think Postgres has limited ability to update the JSON in place.  Instead, you might have to extract the JSON, modify it, and then update the entire value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, here we will use `jsonb_set` method

`jsonb_set(target jsonb, path text[], new_value jsonb)` which will return jsonb object

```
 update carts
        set cart = (
    (select json_agg(val)from 
    (SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN value->>'productid'='8' THEN jsonb_set(value::jsonb, '{cnt}', (((value->>'cnt')::int)+3)::text::jsonb)::json --again convert to json object
    ELSE value END val
      FROM carts,json_array_elements(cart) where id=3)) 
where id=3;
```

Hope it works for you

> EDIT: you can generalized this by creating a function with `id` and
>   `productid` as input parameter.

Comment: You can refer [Json in PostgrSql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html) for more details