# Postgres INSERT ON CONFLICT with JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to use Postgres as a document store and am running into a problem when I'm trying to effectively upsert a document where the Postgres parser doesn't seem to like the JSONB operator.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (data jsonb NOT NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON tbl ((data->>'a'));
```

and I try to insert data with:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (data) VALUES ('{ "a": "b" }'::jsonb) 
  ON CONFLICT (data->>a) 
  DO UPDATE SET data = data || '{ "a": "b" }'::jsonb
```

I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "->>"
```

I've tried data->>a, data->>'a', data->a, and maybe data->'a'.  All of those are

I'd like to leave the identifier column (a in the example) within the JSON and not make it a column on the table.

Is what I'm trying to do currently supported?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two issues you have:

1) You need to add additional parenthesis, like so:

```
ON CONFLICT ((data->>'a'))
```

2) You need to preface the last `data` reference with your table alias, like so:

```
DO UPDATE SET data = tbl.data || '{ "a": "b" }'::jsonb
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  After adding the index I get "ERROR:  column "tbl_data_a_uidx" does not exist"

Comment: I'm using PG 10.3 and it seems to require quoting the jsonb field:  `ON CONFLICT ((data->>'a'))`

Comment: @cjauvin - You are correct - thanks for catching that. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote and got an error witch says : 
there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Comment: @KaramHaj - The error message is pretty clear. You don't have a constraint created on the table that matches the specification/expression in the `ON CONFLICT`. You need to create one.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) on this subject. You might want to use the `json_populate_record` function to fill the table if you are trying to build a json parser. Also see this related question:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb)