# How to perform atom update in embedded schema model with `jsonb_set`?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

How to update only one key in map, I would like to perform it by  `jsonb_set` like here: [stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349699/707729) or in transaction to avoid potential conflicts in database, is it possible with Ecto?

```
defmodule MySuperApp.Profile do
  use MySuperApp.Model
  schema "profiles" do
    field :name, :string
    embeds_one :settigns, MySuperApp.Settigns
  end
  def changeset(struct, params) do
    struct
    |> change
    |> put_embed(:settigns, MySuerApp.Settigns.changeset(model, params))
  end
end
defmodule MySuperApp.Settigns do
  use MySuperApp.Model

  @settigns %{socket: true, page: true, android: false, ios: false}

  embedded_schema do
    field :follow, :boolean

    field :action, :map, default: @settigns
  end

  def changeset(struct, _params) do
    # I would like to update only web key and leave old keys
    model |> change(action: %{web: false}) # this will override old map -> changes: %{action: %{web: false}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ecto currently does not support partial updates of the embeds with the high-level API (like changesets).

You could achieve this by using raw SQL queries through `Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query/4` or in more recent versions `Repo.query/3`.