# node.js and postgresql UPDATE nested JSON key

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a table called "json" in my database, with 2 columns: "id" and "data"

Only one row is stored inside it at the moment, having 1 as id and a JSON structure as data:

```
{
    "elements": {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "n0",
                    "name": "Name here",
                    "color": "#FFFFFF"
                }
            },
            {
                "bob": "hello"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to update a key of the json: "Name here" has to become "updated"

This is what I tried:

```
db.query("UPDATE json SET $1 WHERE data->'elements'->'nodes'->0->'data'->'name'=$2", ['updated', 'Name here'])
```

but I get an error:

> syntax error at or near "'updated'"

Comment: Is the name of the column a problem?

Comment: @tadman I just changed it to "mydata", but still same error...

Comment: Does a simpler version of this query succeed? Might have to do some reductive exploration here.

Comment: @tadman this works for example: `db.query("select data->'elements'->'nodes'->0->'data'->'name' from json where id = 1")`, and returns `[ anonymous { '?column?': 'Name here' } ]`

Comment: Are you sure your finally formatted query is exactly what you think it is? Add event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query) handler to see the exact queries being executed, or just use [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor).

Answer (score 0):

When using the Postgres [JSON navigators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) it's important to terminate your chain with the `text` retrieval navigator `->>` if you want to do comparisons like that:

```
UPDATE json SET $1 WHERE data->'elements'->'nodes'->0->'data'->>'name'=$2
```

That should permit comparing `text` to `text` instead of `json`.

I think you might also be able to use `#>>` to dig the whole way down in one shot:

```
UPDATE json SET $1 WHERE data#>>'{elements,nodes,0,data,name}'=$2
```

Comment: I get the same error: `syntax error at or near "'updated'"` for both of your examples

Comment: [In this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26704636/5638869) I read that postgres updates the whole row even if a change only a little part of it, as JSON in PostgreSQL is intended to store data that do not need to be manipulated. So at this point, if I want to continue in my intent, I could get the JSON (as I shown above), elaborate it, and then send to the database. Does it make sense?

Comment: If you're trying to reassign part of your JSON structure that might not be the syntax to do it. Are you using Postgres 9.6?

Comment: What about `jsonb_set`? It's likely in-place editing is only applicable to the more efficient JSONB column type. That's the same as JSON but it's always compacted into a minimal, canonical form, ignoring any initial layout.

Comment: I will try `jsonb_set`. However I'm using version 9.6.1