# Update key value in jsonb array of objects

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have the following table `company` with a `jsonb` column named `log`: -

```
|code | log
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|K50  | [{"date": "2002-02-06", "type": "Chg Name", "oldvalue": "TEH   "},
         {"date": "2003-08-26", "type": "Chg Name", "oldvalue": "TEOA   "}]
|C44  | [{"date": "2003-05-07", "type": "Chg Name", "oldvalue": "CDE   "}]
```

How to trim the trailing blanks in the `oldvalue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a mix of [`jsonb` functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html):

```
UPDATE company c
SET    log = sub.log2
FROM  (
   SELECT *
   FROM   company c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(l, '{oldvalue}', to_jsonb(rtrim(l->>'oldvalue')))) AS log2
      FROM   jsonb_array_elements(c.log) l
      ) sub
   WHERE  jsonb_typeof(log) = 'array'  -- exclude NULL and non-arrays
   ) sub
WHERE  c.code =  sub.code   -- assuming code is unique
AND    c.log  <> sub.log2;  -- only where column actually changed.
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/051a8/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Had to change last line to sub.log2 <> sub.log though

Comment: Yeah, `c.log  <> sub.log2`, fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL jsonb data type is used for storing JSON data as given. If you want to update any nested value you need to transform the data from your code before it's eligible to be stored in DB. In this scenario, trailing spaces are insignificant. If you wanna update explicitly, that's also possible.

PFB link for that.

[How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Agreed. This was an oversight in the original import script which has since been patched.