# Updating single attribute in json column triggers a full column update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm wondering if this is a bug or normal rails behavior. I'm on 5.2.3

I have a JSON type column on my PostgreSQL db, that looks like this

```
id | name | address(json)
1  | josh | { line1: nil, line2: nil, city: nil }
```

If i do:

```
@account = Account.find(1)
@account.address['city'] = "new york"
@account.save
```

This updates the entire column by re-writing the entire json and every attribute. I imagine this could introduce race conditions in certain use cases, outside of just an address getting updated.

```
 UPDATE "accounts" SET "address" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "accounts"."id" = $3  [["address", "{'is_foreign':false,'line1':'54 Lemon Ave",'line2':null,'city':'new york','state':'NY','country':'US'}"], ["updated_at", "2019-11-15 18:09:07.698093"], ["id", 2]]
```

Comment: Did you try saving the existing json in a variable and then manipulation?

Comment: @RajdeepSingh this happens even if i fetch a clean object from the database with an existing address.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a normal behavior, try this instead:

```
@account = Account.find(1)
address_json = @account.address
address_json['city'] = 'new york'
@account.address = address_json
@account.save
```

Hope that helps!

More helpful info here:

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb)

Comment: Tried this, this would enforce what i don't want which is making the entire address dirty when i just want to edit one attribute

Comment: What version of Rails you are on? 2.4.4 looks like Ruby version

Comment: Sorry it's  5.2.3

Comment: @ryan I don't think that will ever work out. From Rails perspective the address is just one attribute and its dirty as soon as the object id changes. AR does not and probally will never support atomical operations for json/hstore as you should be doing this with a table in the first place. Its a relational database - not mongodb.