# How to update item into the jsonb data type column in PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL,

The task will be like this

```
UPDATE user SET  height= { 'unit': 'Cms', 'value': 170 }

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "{"
```

so is there a way to do UPDATE query that just adds a new element or alters the existing element/node in array/json obejct types in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB in Postgres 9.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 UPDATE user SET height = '{"unit": "Cms", "value": 150}'::jsonb
```

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is because you should provide it as a string

```
update user set height = '{"unit": "Cms", "value": 150}'::jsonb
```