# Updating Multiple Keys in Postgres SQL Json Field Dynamically

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a DB table with Jsonb column

```
number | data
1      | {name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}
```

For updating multiple keys in the same query I use the below query and it works perfectly.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET data = data || '{name: "John", age: 35, city: "Tokyo", active: true}'
WHERE number = 1;
```

But I want to pass the value dynamically to the query using a variable like below but it fails with the error Token 'v_value' is invalid.

```
Declare v_value jsonb;
v_value := 'true';

UPDATE table_name
SET data = data || '{name: "John", age: 35, city: "Tokyo", active: v_value}'
WHERE number = 1;
```

I tried couple of ways like below but nothing worked. Please help.

```
'{name: "John", age: 35, city: "Tokyo", active: '{v_value}'}'
'{name: "John", age: 35, city: "Tokyo", active: $'{v_value}'}'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26703476/495157

Comment: @JGFMK I already went through that post but it didn’t resolve my issue. It will be helpful if someone could share a sample query for the above example.