# Ruby update existing hash value inside value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a model which one of the column is a hash value, like below

```
[3] pry(main)> Activity.find(14)
=> #<Activity:0x00007fe625694070
 id: 14,
 content_basic: {
"content_type"=>"Audio",
 "session_overview_image"=>"https://some_domain.com/392/123-woman.png"}
```

I want to change `content_basic['session_overview_image']` to be `/392/123-woman.png` - how to do that in a rails c?

Comment: Does `content_basic` is a json column and do you want to store `392/123-woman.png` alone as a String ?

Comment: @user11350468 Yes, it's a json column and I want to store all other data as well, I just want to replace `content_basic['session_overview_image']` to be without `https://some_domain.com`

Comment: Which database server you are using ?

Comment: Does it matter? I use postgresql

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26703476/1954610 (Unless there's an `ActiveRecord` interface to do this, that I'm not aware of?? I think you need to use raw SQL.)

Answer (score -1):

How about doing it like this:

```
Activity.find_each do |activity|
  img = activity.content_basic['session_overview_image'].gsub('https://some_domain.com', '')
  activity.content_basic['session_overview_image'] = img
  activity.save
end
```

This assumes that all of the urls have the same domain that you want to remove. If they don't, then a little bit of URI parsing would be required first.

It also assumes that you are not on one of the older Rails versions (3 of before I believe) where you had to tell ActiveRecord that something has changed in the hash when changing serialized column values.