# UPDATE with jsonb_set() only affects one object in nested array

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Trying to update all elements of a nested array in a `jsonb` column, but only one element is updated. My query:

```
update table_ 
 set value_ = jsonb_set(value_,cte.json_path,cte.namevalue,false) FROM (
select 
 vals2->'ao'->'sc'->'name' as namevalue,
  ('{iProps,'||index1-1||',value,rules,'||index2-1||',ao,sc}')::text[] as json_path
from 
  table_, 
  jsonb_array_elements(value_->'iProps') 
  with ordinality arr1(vals1,index1),
  jsonb_array_elements(vals1->'value'->'rules') 
  with ordinality arr2(vals2,index2)
  ) AS cte;
```

See demo with sample value:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e06fba4d035c3c9b7b2d36562ef10354)*

Am unable to understand why this query updates the first object in the `rules` array:

```
iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc -> name = "name1"
```

But not the subsequent ones:

```
iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc -> name = "name2"
iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc -> name = "name3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

The subselect in the `FROM` clause of your `UPDATE` returns ***three*** rows. But every row in the target table can only be updated *once* in a single `UPDATE` command. The result is that you only see the effect of *one* of those three rows.

Or, in the words of [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.8):

> When using `FROM` you should ensure that the join produces at most one
> output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row
> shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it
> does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target
> row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.

Aside: don't call your subquery "cte". It's not a [Common Table Expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

#### Proper `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE table_ t
SET    value_ = jsonb_set(value_, '{iProps}', sub2.new_prop, false)
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(prop, '{value, rules}', new_rules, false)
                    ORDER BY idx1) AS new_prop
   FROM  (
      SELECT t.id, arr1.prop, arr1.idx1
           , jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(rule, '{ao,sc}', rule #> '{ao,sc,name}', false)
                       ORDER BY idx2) AS new_rules
      FROM table_ t
         , jsonb_array_elements(value_->'iProps')       WITH ORDINALITY arr1(prop,idx1)
         , jsonb_array_elements(prop->'value'->'rules') WITH ORDINALITY arr2(rule,idx2)
      GROUP  BY t.id, arr1.prop, arr1.idx1
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY id
   ) sub2
WHERE t.id = sub2.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=06a3afecd8f9e42647779da1c924d4de)*

Use `jsonb_set()` on each object (array element) before aggregating them back into an array. First at the leaf level, and again on the deeper level.

I added `id` as `PRIMARY KEY` to the table. We need some unique column to keep rows separate.

The added `ORDER BY` may or may not be required. Added it to guarantee original order.

Of course, if your data is as regular as the sample, a relational design with dedicated columns might be a simpler alternative. See

- [How to perform update operations on columns of type JSONB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb4/26704636#26704636)

Comment: thanks for helping me out understand. Data is not as regular as the sample data. Can you help me handle for this data in here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=cc93fb9e3abbdf47fd7f0d1d35878b78. I get null value for first object in the array . Insted i should have as it is from original array if the desired path ie. '{ao,sc}' is not null

Comment: Link to fiddle to retrieve the desired result. Can someone take a look? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2ccf9ef6827a4ee24603c791119f46e6

Comment: @jojo: Please start a new *question*  for your new question with everything necessary to understand it. You can always link to this one for context, and drop a forward link here (to also get my attention).

Comment: i have asked a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817635/conditional-update-with-jsonb-set?noredirect=1#comment116376569_65817635