# Conditional update with jsonb_set()

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a table in a Postgres 11.3 database with a `jsonb` column.

Trying to update all objects inside a nested array name `"iProps"`.

If the path `{iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc}` is an object, then the path should be updated from an object to a string with the value
`{iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc -> name}`

If the path `{iProps -> value -> rules -> ao -> sc}` is not present, then the object should be left unchanged.

Test setup with query: [Fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=da347e3e6581e3f767e8a418f2833446)

Desired result:

```
{
    "iProps": [
        {
            "value": {
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "ao": {
                            "set": "get"
                        },
                        "name": "PRule"
                    },
                    {
                        "ao": {
                            "sc":  "name1"
                            
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ao": {
                            "sc": "name2"
                            
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "ao": {
                            "sc":  "name3"                            
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have modified the query and linked in the fiddle. Can someone take a look to see if it's right?

Comment: This just hurts. Use a normal relational data model without JSON, and it will be simple.

Comment: but the data model does not follow a specific schema. Data is not as regular as the sample data

Comment: Please remember to *always* disclose your version of Postgres. The fiddle says 9.5, but please be explicit. And be clear about your objective. I have read it twice and don't understand it.

Comment: Maybe you mean *and not modify the object if there is **no** 'sc' inside 'ao'`*?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A plain [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) should make the difference.

```
UPDATE table_ t
SET    value_ = jsonb_set(value_, '{iProps}', sub2.new_prop, false)
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(prop, '{value, rules}', new_rules, false)
                    ORDER BY idx1) AS new_prop
   FROM  (
      SELECT t.id, arr1.prop, arr1.idx1
           , jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(rule #> '{ao,sc}') = 'object'
                            THEN jsonb_set(rule, '{ao,sc}', rule #> '{ao,sc,name}', false)
                            ELSE rule
                       END
                       ORDER BY idx2) AS new_rules
      FROM table_ t
         , jsonb_array_elements(value_->'iProps')       WITH ORDINALITY arr1(prop,idx1)
         , jsonb_array_elements(prop->'value'->'rules') WITH ORDINALITY arr2(rule,idx2)
      GROUP  BY t.id, arr1.prop, arr1.idx1
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY id
   ) sub2
WHERE t.id = sub2.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d42b50eda30264051679d8e4c972a871)* (Postgres 11!)

To also meet the second filter you added in the update (must be an *object*), check with [`jsonb_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).

The query in [your fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=da347e3e6581e3f767e8a418f2833446) seems needlessly complicated (tl;dr). Also, it does not preserve **original order of array elements**. If that's in fact irrelevant, omit `WITH ORDINALITY` and `ORDER BY` and simplify further:

```sql
UPDATE table_ t
SET    value_ = jsonb_set(value_, '{iProps}', sub2.new_prop, false)
FROM  (
   SELECT id
        , jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(prop, '{value, rules}', new_rules, false)) AS new_prop
   FROM  (
      SELECT t.id, prop
           , jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN jsonb_typeof(rule #> '{ao,sc}') = 'object'
                            THEN jsonb_set(rule, '{ao,sc}', rule #> '{ao,sc,name}', false)
                            ELSE rule
                       END) AS new_rules
      FROM table_ t
         , jsonb_array_elements(value_->'iProps')       prop
         , jsonb_array_elements(prop->'value'->'rules') rule
      GROUP  BY t.id, prop
      ) sub1
   GROUP  BY id
   ) sub2
WHERE t.id = sub2.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=379972d210deea88a4d7228061d37684)*

This typically still preserves the order of array elements (unlike your original). There's just no guarantee with two levels of aggregation.

See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

More advice in my answer to your earlier related question:

- [UPDATE with jsonb_set() only affects one object in nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799161/update-with-jsonb-set-only-affects-one-object-in-nested-array/65800790#65800790)

Comment: Do you think this problem could be solved with a procedural block with loop for update. This query looks complicated for a simple problem.

Comment: @jojo: Certainly doable. But I don't think it will be much simpler. Another alternative would be with **SQL/JSON in Postgres 12** or later. Example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251181/3684