# Unnest objects from a jsonb array into separate rows

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have a table in Postgres 14.9:

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) | state (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }] | [{ "ap": "good", "op2": "bad" }] |
| orange | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "235", "color": "blue" }] | [{ "op": "bad", "op2": "best" }] |
| lemon | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }] | [{ "cp": "best", "op2": "good" }] |

I want this select sql output :

| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB) | state (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | { "code": "156", "color": "red"} | { "ap": "good", "op2": "bad" } |
| apple | { "code": "156", "color": "blue"} | { "ap": "good", "op2": "bad" } |
| orange | { "code": "156", "color": "red" } | { "op": "bad", "op2": "best" } |
| lemon | { "code": "156", "color": "red" } | { "cp": "best", "op2": "good" } |
| lemon | { "code": "156", "color": "blue"} | { "cp": "best", "op2": "good" } |

My attempt:

```
SELECT
    "Name (Txt)"
 ,  jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color')  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
 ,  state::JSONB "
FROM your_table,
     jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem,
     state::JSONB
WHERE elem->>'code' = '156';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could unnest your array with `JSONB_TO_RECORDSET`, then remap your json objects with `JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT`.

```
SELECT tab.name, 
       JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT('code', cte.code, 'color', cte.color) AS "Detail (JSONB)",
       tab.state AS "State (JSONB)" 
FROM       tab
CROSS JOIN JSONB_TO_RECORDSET(tab.Detail) cte(  
               code  VARCHAR(30),
               color VARCHAR(30)
           )
```

"**Output**":

| name | Detail (JSONB) | State (JSONB) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | {"code":"156","color":"red"} | [{"ap":"good","op2":"bad"}] |
| apple | {"code":"156","color":"blue"} | [{"ap":"good","op2":"bad"}] |
| orange | {"code":"156","color":"yellow"} | [{"op":"bad","op2":"best"}] |
| lemon | {"code":"156","color":"red"} | [{"cp":"best","op2":"good"}] |
| lemon | {"code":"156","color":"blue"} | [{"cp":"best","op2":"good"}] |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kVhhTF26mGfSEJCbYfeHgz/1).

Answer (score 2):

[**`jsonb_array_elements()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.1.1.2.1) does **exactly** what you are asking for, in a single step:

```sql
SELECT name, jsonb_array_elements(detail) AS detail, state
FROM   tbl;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X0rN5Gao)

See:

- [Query for array elements inside JSON type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736742/query-for-array-elements-inside-json-type/22737710#22737710)

If there can be empty arrays or `null` in `detail`, here is a variant to preserve all input rows:

```sql
SELECT t.name, e.detail, t.state
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.detail) AS e(detail) ON true;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

Of course, `detail` must be a jsonb *array*, or you get an error. You might test with `jsonb_typeof()` first:

See:

- [Conditional update with jsonb_set()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65817635/conditional-update-with-jsonb-set/65832572#65832572)

Answer (score 1):

Considering `yellow` in your output is a typo.

I have a table with the name `test_table`. Schema of the table is

```
name (text)
detail (jsonb)
state (jsonb)
```

Following query will give the desired output.

```
select                              
  table_1.name, 
  table_1.details, 
  table_2.state 
from 
  (
    select 
      name, 
      jsonb_array_elements(detail) as details 
    from 
      test_table
  ) table_1 
  join (
    select 
      name, 
      jsonb_array_elements(state) as state 
    from 
      test_table
  ) table_2 on table_1.name = table_2.name 
where 
  table_1.details ->> 'code' = '156';
```