# Can PostgreSQL Select after JOIN Two column jsonb array?

Tags: postgresql

my postgresql version is 14.9
there is a_table:

```
| Name (Txt) | Detail (JSONB)                                                           | state (JSONB)                        | 
| ---------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------------ | -------------------------------------|
| apple      | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }]  | [{ "color": "blue", "op2": "bad" }]  |
| orange     | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "235", "color": "blue" }]  | [{ "color": "blue", "op2": "best" }] |
| lemon      | [{ "code": "156", "color": "red" }, { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }]  | [{ "color": "red", "op2": "good" }]  |
```

I want this select sql output :

```
| Name (Txt)   | Detail (JSONB)                           | state (JSONB)                      | 
| --------     | -----------------------------------------| -----------------------------------|
| apple        | { "code": "156", "color": "red"}         |                                    |
| apple        | { "code": "156", "color": "blue"}        | { "color": "blue", "op2": "bad" }  |
| orange       | { "code": "156", "color": "red" }        |                                    |
| lemon        | { "code": "156", "color": "red" }        | { "color": "red", "op2": "good" }  |
| lemon        | { "code": "156", "color": "blue" }       |                                    |
```

I did try this sql :

```
SELECT
    "Name (Txt)"
 ,  jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color')  AS "Detail (JSONB)"
 ,  state::JSONB "
FROM your_table,
     jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem,
     state::JSONB
WHERE elem->>'code' = '156';
```

Comment: Looks like this post is a duplicate of the post you've already written some minutes ago [Unnest jsonb array into array objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77080633/unnest-jsonb-array-into-array-objects)

Comment: ah that is my mistake quistion. so i upload post again. sorry.

Comment: You can just delete this one again

Comment: this posting is my real question.  but  Unnest jsonb array into array objects is useful also . so I don't delete.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in your query a LEFT JOIN is required in order to incorporate rows from the "state" JSONB collection as well. Otherwise, the query is almost accurate. However if you want to make the query simpler, you should also use a common table expression (CTE).
Try this SQL statement:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        "Name (Txt)",
        jsonb_build_object('code', elem->>'code', 'color', elem->>'color') AS "Detail (JSONB)",
        elem->>'code' AS "code_filter"
    FROM your_table
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements("Detail (JSONB)") AS elem
    WHERE elem->>'code' = '156'
)

SELECT
    CTE."Name (Txt)",
    CTE."Detail (JSONB)",
    state::jsonb AS "state (JSONB)"
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN your_table ON CTE."Name (Txt)" = your_table."Name (Txt)" AND CTE."code_filter" = ANY(string_to_array(your_table.state::text, ','::text));
```

Hope it gives you desired result :)