# Get occurrences where jsonb column contains string, for an array of strings

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given table:

```
Team = {
 names: jsonb<string[]>
}
```

Then given a string array

```
newStudents = ["Karen", "Sarah", "Tom"]
```

How would I go about getting the occurrences of each names that appeared in the table within the jsonb?

Expected return something like

```
[
  {
    "Karen",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    "Tom",
    count: 2
  },
  {
    "Sarah",
    count: 0
  },
]
```

*also, does a GIN index help at all here?

Comment: Please be more specific. "Appear" how exactly? As key name? Your version of Postgres?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter yes like loop through the array and count all rows where the key name appears in the jsonb, pg version 15

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about top-level key names or array elements in the JSON documents, use the [`jsonb` **`?|`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to filter quickly. Then join unnested  document keys to unnested array items, and count:

```sql
SELECT key, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT jsonb_object_keys(names)
   FROM   team
   WHERE  names ?| '{Karen,Sarah,Tom}'  -- optional, but recommended!
   ) sub(key)
JOIN   unnest('{Karen,Sarah,Tom}'::text[]) key USING (key)
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Top-level key names are guaranteed to be unique.
This can use a GIN index on team(names). See:

- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26499266/whats-the-proper-index-for-querying-structures-in-arrays-in-postgres-jsonb/27708358#27708358)

Comment: {
 "status": "error",
 "message": "cannot call jsonb_object_keys on an array"
}

names is an array of string in jsonb format

Comment: SELECT key, count(*)
FROM  (
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements(names)
   FROM   team
   WHERE  names ?| '{Karen,Sarah,Tom}' 
   ) sub(key)

GROUP  BY 1;

^ however, editing ur query the above works, but idk if its proper.

Comment: If all your JSON values are arrays, `jsonb_array_elements_text()` is the proper tool. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684 And declaring as much in the question to begin with would be the proper approach here on SO. If you aren't sure, test with `jsonb_typeof()`and fork accordingly. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65832572/939860 If you are sure, a plain Postgres array (without the JSON wrapper) would be simpler.