# Update jsonb column to replace specific element

Tags: postgresql, replace, jsonb

I want to update a jsonb column to replace an element of array inside it e.g Tv to TV. I am using postgresql 12.4 with 5M rows on that table.

**Top 10 Rows:**

```
categories
["Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Parking", "Tv", "Child Friendly", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Hot Tub", "Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Pool", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Hot Tub", "Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Balcony/Terrace", "Parking", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Child Friendly", "Pool", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Balcony/Terrace", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Parking", "Tv", "Pool", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Hot Tub", "Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Parking", "Balcony/Terrace", "Tv", "Child Friendly", "Internet", "Pet Friendly", "Laundry"]
["Hot Tub", "Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Balcony/Terrace", "Parking", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Pool", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Parking", "Tv", "Internet", "Laundry"]
["Air Conditioner", "Kitchen", "Bedding/Linens", "Parking", "Tv", "Wheelchair Accessible", "Internet", "Laundry"]
```

**What is working:**

```
UPDATE test_jsonb_update 
SET amenity_categories = replace(amenity_categories::TEXT,'"Tv"','"TV"')::jsonb 
WHERE id < 10;
```

**What I want:**

I want to know other alternatives to update that element on jsonb column. I've seen this example
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349699/1138192 and I want to use something like  `jsonb_set` on my
case also. Let me know other alternatives and best practices as I have 5M records to do update that

Comment: Do you want to keep the order?

Comment: not necessarily, If I can then it will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO is your way the most efficient. In any other ways (**if you want to keep the order!**) you need to expand the array elements into separate rows (either for retrieving the index of the old `"Tv"` to set the new `"TV"` to the same position using jsonb_set or for string search/replace) and reaggregate all...

[demos:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=318c0d8216e542ec0444aaba191473ae)

```
SELECT
    id,
    jsonb_agg(CASE WHEN elem = 'Tv' THEN 'TV' ELSE elem END) as new_array
FROM mytable,
    jsonb_array_elements_text(mydata) as elem
GROUP BY id
```

---

If you really want to use `jsonb_set` (which make no sense here, I believe) you could do something like:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_set(mydata, ARRAY[s.elem_id]::text[], '"TV"') - 'Tv'
FROM mytable t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        id,
        elem_id
    FROM mytable,
        jsonb_array_elements_text(mydata) WITH ORDINALITY as elem(value, elem_id)
    WHERE elem.value = 'Tv'
)s ON s.id = t.id
```

1. Expand the array elements and show their indexes with `WITH ORDINALITY`
2. Now you can use these indexes to place the new `"TV"` element to the right place with `jsonb_set()`
3. Afterwards you need to remove the old `"Tv"` element from the updated array.

Finally do the update with:

```
UPDATE mytable t
SET mydata = s.my_array
FROM (
    -- query
) s
WHERE t.id = s.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The ordering on your json array doesn't seem fixed, so this should do the job and avoid any unnesting.

```sql
UPDATE ...
SET amenity_categories = (amenity_categories - 'Tv') || jsonb '["TV"]'
WHERE amenity_categories ? 'Tv';
```

Comment: This only works if the order does not matters

Comment: Yep. Otherwise you need to unnest `WITH ORDINALITY` as in your example. Or write a custom function.