# How to update a Jsonb type column in postgres database using normal sql query?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core

I have defined a Class KeyValue as jsonb type in one of tables in Postgres.

```
Public Class KeyValue
{
public string Key { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}

Public Class Table
{
  [Column("tags", TypeName = "jsonb")]
  public KeyValue Tags { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting error "KeyValue isn't natively supported by Npgsql or your PostgreSQL. To use it with a PostgreSQL composite you need to specify DataTypeName or to map it, please refer to the documentation"

Comment: In which case did you get this error? Could you please provide more information?

Comment: I am trying to update my table like "Update Table set Tags='KeyValue Class Data'  where Id=someid"

Comment: In this case you can't update jsonb data in table like this. First you need to fetch the required data, make some changes inside it and after that update the whole jsonb object in table.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4