# Update part of a string from a jsonb column in postgres database

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, jsonb

I have to modify part of a link in a jsonb column from a postgres database.

The object looks like this:

```json
{
  "large": {
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "url": "https://bucket1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/large_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12.jpg",
    "hash": "large_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "large_ansgar-scheffold-IZZ78Ugqsow-unsplash.jpg",
    "path": null,
    "size": 85.7,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 667
  },
  "small": {
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "url": "https://bucket1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/small_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12.jpg",
    "hash": "small_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "small_ansgar-scheffold-IZZ78Ugqsow-unsplash.jpg",
    "path": null,
    "size": 24.44,
    "width": 500,
    "height": 333
  },
  "medium": {
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "url": "https://bucket1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/medium_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12.jpg",
    "hash": "medium_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "medium_ansgar-scheffold-IZZ78Ugqsow-unsplash.jpg",
    "path": null,
    "size": 50.9,
    "width": 750,
    "height": 500
  },
  "thumbnail": {
    "ext": ".jpg",
    "url": "https://bucket1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/thumbnail_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12.jpg",
    "hash": "thumbnail_ansgar_scheffold_IZZ_78_Ugqsow_unsplash_498662ba12",
    "mime": "image/jpeg",
    "name": "thumbnail_ansgar-scheffold-IZZ78Ugqsow-unsplash.jpg",
    "path": null,
    "size": 6.88,
    "width": 234,
    "height": 156
  }
}
```

I want to change 'bucket1' from each url into 'bucket2'.

I can change the whole url like this:

```
UPDATE public.files 
SET formats = jsonb_set(formats, '{large,url}', '"new-url"')
```

But how can I change only part of it? Can I somehow combine jsonb_set with regexp_replace?
I thought about converting it to string and back but I am not sure how I should do that.

Comment: relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4

Answer (score 0):

To update the URL for each parent key `"large"`, `"small"`, etc, you will want to run `jsonb_set(js, '{<key>, url}'::text[], replace(...)::json)` for each key, possibly nesting `jsonb_set` set calls in a single `set` clause in an `update` query. However, due to the fairly large number of keys to be updated in this example and possible future variability in the keys in each `json` object, you can use a recursive `cte` to update your `json` in-place:

```
with recursive cte(js, vals, c) as (
   select jsonb_set(t2.js, ('{'||(t2.vals ->> 0)::text||',url}')::text[], replace((t2.js -> (t2.vals ->> 0)::text -> 'url')::text, 'bucket1'::text, 'bucket2'::text)::jsonb), t2.vals, 1 
   from (select t.js, jsonb_agg(t1) vals from tbl t cross join jsonb_object_keys(t.js) t1 group by t.js) t2
   union all
   select jsonb_set(t2.js, ('{'||(t2.vals ->> t2.c)::text||',url}')::text[], replace((t2.js -> (t2.vals ->> t2.c)::text -> 'url')::text, 'bucket1'::text, 'bucket2'::text)::jsonb), t2.vals, t2.c+1
   from cte t2 where t2.c < jsonb_array_length(t2.vals)
)
select jsonb_pretty(t.js) from cte t where t.c = jsonb_array_length(t.vals)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0eff4a0b1b3c4b39a94e3f616167ddda).