# How to use jsonb_set with "WITH AS" variable?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am trying to use `jsonb_set` to change a single attribute of a jsonb object within my Postgres table.

I am using `WITH random_string AS` to set the variable `random_string` to a random hexidecimal value and then pass that string into my `UPDATE` query. However, it is not working.

This is the code I am using:

```
WITH random_string AS (SELECT  substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25)::varchar)

UPDATE 
    teams 
SET 
    profile = jsonb_set(profile, '{api_key}', random_string)
WHERE
    team_id="abc123";
```

The error I get seems to think I am trying to access a column that does not exist, because this is how you would normally reference a column.

```
Postgres query failed, PostgresPlugin query failed to execute: error: column "random_string" does not exist
```

Question: **How do I use my random_string variable in the jsonb_set function to update this attribute?**

Comment: related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703476/how-to-perform-update-operations-on-columns-of-type-jsonb-in-postgres-9-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three issues. First, `WITH` statement gives a table-like result, not a variable. Define a table with a single column and use its name in the `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`. Next, the third argument of `jsonb_set()` is `jsonb`, use `to_jsonb()`. And last, a proper text literal is in single quotes `'abc123'`.

```sql
WITH var(random_string) AS (SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25)::varchar)

UPDATE 
    teams 
SET 
    profile = jsonb_set(profile, '{api_key}', to_jsonb(random_string))
FROM
    var
WHERE
    team_id = 'abc123';
```