# Update query for inner json array for jsonb type

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

What query should i use to update all employee data where employee with desig TL should be updated with salaray 20000

table structure

| vertical_id | name | employee_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | accounts | {employees:[{"empId":1,"desig":"TL","sal":10000},{"empId":2,"desig":"staff","sal":5000},{"empId":3,"desig":"staff","sal":}]} |
| 2 | HR | {employees:[{"empId":1,"desig":"TL","sal":10000},{"empId":2,"desig":"staff","sal":5000},{"empId":3,"desig":"staff","sal":}]} |

on updating as a result, we need

| vertical_id | name | employee_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | accounts | {employees:[{"empId":1,"desig":"TL","sal":20000},{"empId":2,"desig":"staff","sal":5000},{"empId":3,"desig":"staff","sal":}]} |
| 2 | HR | {employees:[{"empId":1,"desig":"TL","sal":20000},{"empId":2,"desig":"staff","sal":5000},{"empId":3,"desig":"staff","sal":}]} |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a couple of JSON operators and functions.

```sql
UPDATE employees
SET employee_data = jsonb_set(
    employee_data,
    '{employees}',
    (
        SELECT jsonb_agg(
            CASE
                WHEN value ->> 'desig' = 'TL' THEN jsonb_set(value, '{sal}', to_jsonb(20000)::jsonb)
                ELSE value
            END
        )
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(employee_data -> 'employees') AS t(value)
    ),
    true
)
WHERE employee_data @> '{"employees":[{"desig":"TL"}]}';
```

You can see it in use here: https://dbfiddle.uk/gCFv5TUi

A not-so-similar answer showing the use of JSON functions in Postgres: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349699/7368018

Comment: Above query worked for me thanks, If same data is an array how can we update for desig with TL & if salary less than 20000 to 20000?

```
INSERT INTO employees (vertical_id, name, employee_data) VALUES
(1, 'accounts', '{
    "employees": [
        {"empId":  1, "details": [{"desig": "TL", "sal":  10000}]},
        {"empId":  2, "details": [{"desig": "staff", "sal":  5000}]},
        {"empId":  3, "details": [{"desig": "staff"}]}
    ]
}')
```