# Query combinations with nested array of records in JSON datatype

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm working on a Rails application that utilizes the Postgres `JSON` data type. I have a JSON column called `data` in a table called `reports`. Let's say I have multiple entries like this:

```
Entry 1: {"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"background.png"}
Entry 2: {"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barC.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"bacakground.png"}
Entry 3: {"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "middle"},{"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "middle"}],"background":"background.png"}
Entry 4: {"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 3, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"backgroundA.png"}
```

What I would like to do is return the different combinations of entries that have the same album, src, and background (NOTE: within the `objects` node, order of array elements does not matter). For instance, the query should match entries 1,3 as one group, entry 2, as another, and etc. The goal is to find the top 3 most common combinations. I know how to do this using Ruby, but I would have to query a large sample of entries, then iterate over all of them. It seems more efficient to use Postgres if it can handle this task. I'm not enough of a SQL expert to know if this is possible.

This is the result I am looking for. Within `objects`, entries 1 and 3 both contain `{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png"}, {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png"}`, as well as both have matching `backgrounds`. I would like to group them as one combination with a count of 2.

Since entry 2 does not match any entries under this criteria, then it is another combination with a count of 1. Entry 4 is also considered another combination with a count of 1. So the result I'm after would be:

```
ids  |  count
--------------
1,3  | 2
2    | 1
4    | 1
```

or

```
combinations                                                                                                                               | count
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},  {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],  "background":"background.png"}  | 2
{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},  {"album": 2, "src":"barC.png", "pos": "top"}],  "background":"bacakground.png"} | 1
{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},  {"album": 3, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],  "background":"backgroundA.png"} | 1
```

Whichever is easier to achieve.

In my actual data, I have values other than just `album` and `src` in the array of JSON within the `objects` node. You'll notice that I've included `pos` to show this case. I only care about using the `album`, `src`, and `background` values to match the combos. I was hoping to ignore any other values.

**Note**

When I was testing [Erwin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880705/1323305), I kept getting this error and I know why:

> ```
> ERROR:  cannot call json_populate_recordset on a nested object
> ```

My json values are are actually a little more complex. For example:

```
{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top", filters: []},  {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top", filters: []}
```

Obviously, `filters` is a nested object and is not supported by `json_populate_recordset`. However, I think I can work around this if there is no simple alternative. Again, I assume this is possible?

**UPDATE**

Due to a typo in my sample data above (which was my fault), this solution is a bit incomplete. When the typo is fixed, it solution does not work. Find the answer to that situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872737/1323305). But [Erwin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26880705/1323305) is still an answer to cases similar to what was described above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given this table (which you should have provided in a form like this):

```sql
CREATE TABLE reports (rep_id int primary key, data json);
INSERT INTO reports (rep_id, data)
VALUES 
  (1, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"background.png"}')
, (2, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barC.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"bacakground.png"}')
, (3, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "middle"},{"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "middle"}],"background":"background.png"}')
, (4, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 3, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"backgroundA.png"}')
;
```

#### JSON records of well known translatable type

Use [**`json_populate_recordset()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) for unnesting the recordset `"objects"`. The function requires a registered row type to define the names and data types of resulting columns. For the purpose of this demo or generally for ad-hoc queries, a **temp table** modeled after `"objects"` can provide the same:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE obj(album int, src text, pos text);
```

To find *the top 3 most common combinations ... of entries that have the same `album`, `src`, and `background`*:

```sql
SELECT array_agg(r.rep_id) AS ids, count(*) AS ct
FROM   reports r
     , json_populate_recordset(null::obj, r.data->'objects') o
GROUP  BY r.data->>'background'
        , o.album
        , o.scr
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

Each object counts, no matter whether from the same row or not. You did not define how to handle that exactly. Consequently, `rep_id` can pop up multiple times in the array `ids`. Add `DISTINCT` to `array_agg()` to fold possible duplicates. The count `ct` can be greater then the length of the array `ids` in this case.

Requires Postgres 9.3 for the JSON functions and operators and the [implicit `JOIN LATERAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).

#### JSON records of unknown or untranslatable type

[`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE) just unnests the json array without transforming the result into an SQL row. Access individual fields with JSON operators accordingly.

```
SELECT array_agg(r.rep_id) AS ids, count(*) AS ct
FROM   reports r
     , json_array_elements(r.data->'objects') o
GROUP  BY r.data->>'background'
        , o->>'album'
        , o->>'scr'
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

Comment: That's it, the second option works perfectly! I added `DISTINCT` as suggested to get the exact result I need. Thank you again for helping and teaching me some new stuff. You are a gentleman and a scholar.

Comment: Hey @ErwinBrandstetter, I was hoping you can help me with an issue I came across for this. I had to make it another question because it's requires a lot of discussion and doesn't seem to fit here. Here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848171/querying-combinations-of-json-returns-odd-results)

Comment: Actually I just discovered that our sample data only worked because there was a typo. In your sample data, value `2` has `"background":"bacakground.png"`. If I correct the typo and make it `"background":"background.png"`, I no longer get the results I need. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @pacothelovetaco: The typo is in your original data. Your new question (plus solution) solves a different problem: a bit more complex than this one.

Comment: For anyone else running into the problem, you'll need to use jsonb_array_elements on a jsonb datatype (note the extra B).