# How to convert postgresql 9.4 jsonb to object without function/server side language

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Is it possible to transform postgresql 9.4 jsonb data without creating function and without using any server side programming language?

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,data JSONB);
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('{"a":1,"b":2}');
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('{"a":3,"b":4,"c":7}');
INSERT INTO test(data) VALUES('{"a":5,"b":5,"d":8}');
SELECT * FROM test;
 id |           data       
----+-------------------------
  1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
  2 | {"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 7}
  3 | {"a": 5, "b": 5, "d": 8}
```

to transform it into:

```
 {1:[1,2,null,null],2:[3,4,7,null],3:[5,5,null,8]}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use **[`jsonb_populate_record()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE)** (or `json_populate_record()` for `json`) with a well known row type as target. You can use a temp table to register a type for ad-hoc use (if you can't use an *existing* table or custom composite type):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE obj(a int, b int, c int, d int);
```

Then:

```
SELECT t.id, d.*
FROM   test t
     , jsonb_populate_record(null::obj, t.data) d;
```

**Or** use **[`jsonb_to_record()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-TABLE)** (or `json_to_record()` for `json`) and provide a column definition list with the call:

```
SELECT t.id, d.*
FROM   test t
     , jsonb_to_record(t.data) d(a int, b int, c int, d int);
```

**Or** extract and cast **each field** individually:

```
SELECT id, (data->>'a')::int AS a, (data->>'b')::int AS b
         , (data->>'c')::int AS c, (data->>'d')::int AS d
FROM   test;
```

All three work for `json` and `jsonb` alike. Just use the respective function variant.

Related:

- [Query combinations with nested array of records in JSON datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-for-postgresql-json-datatype/26880705#26880705)

Comment: @Kokizzu: That one is actually new in 9.4. The other two options are in pg 9.3, too (for `json`).

Comment: postgre is awesome XD (I'm switching back from NoSQL to postgre because of jsonb)

Comment: @Kokizzu: Welcome back. :) And [never call it "postgre"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines). It's `PostgreSQL`, `Postgres` or `pg`.

Comment: For me this worked only if I replaced `t.data` with `t.data::jsonb`

Comment: @EliadL: Like I mentioned, there two variants for most JSON functions. `json_to_record()` and `jsonb_to_record()` for instance. Use the appropriate one if possible instead of casting ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I think you may be missing my point. It's not about `json` vs `jsonb`, but  implicit vs explicit.

Comment: If you're getting an error containing "cannot be referenced from this part of the query", it might be related to your `JOIN`s. This may help solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63938696/764945

Answer (score 1):

create an new data type.

```
create type fourints as (a int, b int,c int,d int);
```

then:

```
SELECT t.id, d.*
FROM   test1 t
     , jsonb_populate_record(null::fourints, t.data) d;
```