# Extract JSON content in Metabase SQL query

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, metabase

Using: `Django==2.2.24`, `Python=3.6`, PostgreSQL is underlying DB
Working with Django ORM, I can easily make all sort of queries, but I started using   Metabase, and my SQL might be a bit rusty.

**The problem:**
I am trying to get a count of the items in a list, under a key in a dictionary, stored as a `JSONField`:

```
from django.db import models
from jsonfield import JSONField

class MyTable(models.Model):
  data_field = JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
```

Example of the dictionary stored in `data_field`:

```
{..., "my_list": [{}, {}, ...], ...}
```

Under `"my_list"` key, the value stored is a list, which contains a number of other dictionaries.
In Metabase, I am trying to get a count for the number of dictionaries in the list, but even more basic things, none of which work.

**Some stuff I tried:**
Attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(elem->'my_list') as my_list_count
FROM my_table, json_object_keys(data_field:json) AS elem
```

Error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" Position: 226
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(elem->'my_list') as my_list_count
FROM my_table, JSON_OBJECT_KEYS(data_field:json) AS elem
```

Error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" Position: 233
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(data_field->'my_list'::json)
FROM my_table
```

Error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "my_list" is invalid. Position: 162 Where: JSON data, line 1: my_list
```

Attempt:

```
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(data_field, '$.my_list'))
FROM my_table
```

Error:

```
ERROR: function json_query_array(text, unknown) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 140
```

Basically, I think the issue is that I am using the wrong signatures (most of the time) in the methods I am trying to use.

I used this query to make sure I can at least get the keys from the dictionary:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT_KEYS(data_field::json)
FROM my_table
```

I was not able to use `JSON_OBJECT_KEYS()` without adding the `::json` cast, I was getting this error:

```
ERROR: function json_object_keys(text) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 127
```

But with the json cast, I am getting all the keys as intended.

Thank you for taking a look!

**EDIT:**
I also found this [interesting article with different solution](https://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/values-from-nested-json/) but none of the solutions worked.
Also seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39010601/extract-key-value-from-json-objects-in-postgres) which did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some more digging around, I found [this](https://predictivehacks.com/?all-tips=how-to-get-the-key-value-from-json-objects-in-postgres) article, which had the correct format/syntax.

This code is what I used to fetch the list from the JSON object successfully:

```
select data_field::json->'my_list' as the_list
from my_table
```

Then, I used `json_array_length()` to get the number of elements:

```
select json_array_length(data_field::json->'my_list') as number_of_elements
from my_table
```

All done! :)

**EDIT:**
I just found the reason to this whole shenanigan.
In the code (which goes years back) we used this package:

```py
jsonfield==1.0.3
```

And used this way:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
```

The issue is that in the background, Postgres saves the data as a string, so it needs to be cast into a JSON.
Later Django introduced its own `JSONField`, which stores data as you would expect, without a need to cast:

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```