# Selecting only the values from a json column? Or perhaps extracting the value from a record?

Tags: json, postgresql

Say I have the following table that contains text interpreted as Json ([dbFiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJzJoF4Xu2VHhbX3tayaad/1)):

```
create table the_table(the_json text);

insert into the_table (the_json) values('{"foo": 42, "bar": 43}');
```

*(Side note: yes, the `the_json` column here is indeed `text` and not `json`. I can't change the schema in my case, so I use `::json`)*

Now it looks like:

```
the_json
--------
{"foo": 42, "bar": 43}
```

I would like to select *only the values* `42` and `43` from this json, I **don't** care about the keys `foo` and `bar`.

Fortunately, [Postgres provides](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) a `json_each` which seems to get me pretty close!

```
> select json_each(the_json::json) from the_table;
json_each
---------
(foo,42)
(bar,43)
```

Now the documentation says these are of type `setof record ( key text, value text )` and so the value can be accessed as `value`, but alas I must be missing the magic syntax because I can't seem to extract the value:

```
> select value from (select jsonb_each(the_json::jsonb) from the_table) as results;
error: column "value" does not exist
```

What is the `magic_syntax` I'm missing that will let me select only the values from this json object? *Here's the ([dbFiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJzJoF4Xu2VHhbX3tayaad/1)) again.*

```
> select json_each(the_json::json) ??? magic_syntax ??? from the_table;
value
-----
42
43
```

Answer (score 1):

A hah! I finally found the answer from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62177837/446554).

```
select js.value
  from the_table,
    json_each(the_table.the_json::json) as js;
```