# Postgresql query to retrieve data from a column where data is stored as object

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I have column named items where data is stored as object.
eg: {"productId":"books","quantity":10,"declaredValue":31}

How can i retrieve the productId and its quantity from the above object using pgsql query ??
I am using PostgreSQL. I want to create jasper reports.
[I tried this solution but it did'nt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27181980/how-to-convert-postgresql-9-4-jsonb-to-object-without-function-server-side-langu)

Answer (score 0):

col_name->>'key' where key is productId and quantity. Note that key value is CASE SENSITIVE. and key value should be within SINGLE QUOTES.