# Postgres - How to fix LATERAL Query Error

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, join

I have a LATERAL query problem on postgresql. I didnt found any solution on internet. Can you help me?

My query example is this:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=665e3efb0c8229718cf098cf4873df91

My query is this:

```
SELECT
    bonuses.bonus_id
FROM bonuses,
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) getRules(obj),
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'providers') rule_providers(id),
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'games') rule_games(id)
    INNER JOIN provider_games ON provider_games.provider_id = rule_providers.id::bigint
    or provider_games.provider_game_id = rule_games.id::bigint
```

I am getting bellow error:

```
[42P01] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "rule_providers" Hint: There is an entry for table "rule_providers", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Position: 335
```

When I use below query everthing is okay. Its working. It explodes when I use more than one lateral.

```
SELECT
    bonuses.bonus_id
FROM bonuses,
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) getRules(obj),
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'providers') rule_providers(id)
    INNER JOIN provider_games ON provider_games.provider_id = rule_providers.id::bigint
```

My table structure is below:

```
create table provider_games (
    provider_game_id bigserial not null
    constraint provider_games_pkey primary key
);

create table bonuses (
    bonus_id bigserial not null
    constraint bonuses_pkey primary key,
    rules jsonb
);

INSERT INTO bonuses (rules) VALUES ('[{"rule":{"games":["9179","7821","7915"]}},{"rule":{"providers":["19","11"]}}]');
INSERT INTO provider_games (provider_game_id, provider_id) VALUES (9179, 19);
INSERT INTO provider_games (provider_game_id, provider_id) VALUES (7915, 11);

TABLE bonuses;
TABLE provider_games;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code mixes implicit and explicit joins. This is not a good practice: they have different prescendence rules, which is causing subtle issues such as the one you are having.

Don't mix join styles - be consistent. Matter of fact, always use standard, explicit joins:

```
SELECT bonuses.bonus_id
FROM bonuses
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) getRules(obj)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'providers') rule_providers(id)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(obj -> 'rule' -> 'games') rule_games(id)
INNER JOIN provider_games 
    ON provider_games.provider_id = rule_providers.id::bigint
    OR provider_games.provider_game_id = rule_games.id::bigint
```

Comment: Thank you so much your reply. I haven't tried it in various ways, but it doesn't return results. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e008d8799dee3ab46a4919b9aeee1fc5

Comment: @omero: my answer fixes the error that you were getting. Why it doesn't generate the result you want is, in my opinion, a different question, that would require that you explain the logic you want to implement, and provide desired results. I would recommend asking *a new question* for this.

Answer (score 0):

When I made some changes, I got the right result. Thank you @GMB

```
SELECT
   bonus_id
FROM bonuses,
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) getProviderRules(games),
    LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(bonuses.rules) getGamesRules(providers)
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(providers -> 'rule' -> 'providers') rule_providers(id)
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements_text(games -> 'rule' -> 'games') rule_games(id)
    INNER JOIN provider_games
        ON provider_games.provider_id = rule_providers.id::bigint
        OR provider_games.provider_game_id = rule_games.id::bigint
GROUP BY bonus_id
```