# Querying combinations of JSON returns odd results

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This is a followup to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-with-nested-array-of-records-in-json-datatype). I seem to have come across an edge case and I don't understand why I'm getting the wrong results. Using the data from the linked question, 
I can group them into combinations that use the same album, src, and background.

For instance, using this data:

```
CREATE TABLE reports (rep_id int primary key, data json);
INSERT INTO reports (rep_id, data)
VALUES 
  (1, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"background.png"}'),
  (2, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 2, "src":"barC.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"background.png"}'),
  (3, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "middle"},{"album": 2, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "middle"}],"background":"background.png"}'),
  (4, '{"objects":[{"album": 1, "src":"fooA.png", "pos": "top"},   {"album": 3, "src":"barB.png", "pos": "top"}],   "background":"backgroundA.png"}')
;
```

and this is the query:

```
SELECT distinct array_agg(distinct r.rep_id) AS ids, count(*) AS ct
FROM   reports r
  , json_array_elements(r.data->'objects') o
GROUP  BY r.data->>'background'
   , o->>'album'
   , o->>'src'
ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT  5;
```

I get these results, which are incorrect:

```
  ids    | ct 
---------+----
 {1,2,3} |  3
 {1,3}   |  2
 {2}     |  1
 {4}     |  1
```

What I want is this

```
  ids    | ct 
---------+----
 {1,3}   |  2
 {2}     |  1
 {4}     |  1
```

If I change the `background` values so that they are varied, then it does work as expected but the counts are still off. So what I'm gather is the grouping by `background` may be a cause for the issue. But I don't know why. I can do without the counts, I just mainly need the ids grouped for matching combinations that use the same file, album, and background.

**Edit**
I had to edit my question. It turns out my sample data had an error and I was never getting the correct results. So I am looking for a query that works if possible.

Comment: You need to describe *why* the desired result is what you want. Else it's hard to guess.

Answer (score 1):

A kind person from Postgresql's IRC channel helped find the answer and craft the correct query. The credit is actually his, not mine.

He helped realize that the albums and srcs should be added to arrays for comparison. For instance:

```
SELECT array_agg(rep_id), count(*) AS ct
FROM (SELECT rep_id, 
             data->>'background' as background, 
             array_agg(o->>'album' order by o->>'album') as albums, 
             array_agg(o->>'src' order by o->>'album') as srcs  
           FROM reports r, 
           json_array_elements(r.data->'objects') o 
           GROUP BY rep_id) s 
GROUP BY background, albums, srcs
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it but it works. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo, change `'scr'` to `'src'`. But your query is correct, just take a look at your query without grouping:

```
select
     r.rep_id, r.data->>'background' as background, o->>'album' as album, o->>'src' as src
from reports r, json_array_elements(r.data->'objects') o;

------------------------------------------------------------
REP_ID  BACKGROUND      ALBUM   SRC
1       background.png      1   fooA.png
1       background.png      2   barB.png
2       background.png      2   barB.png
2       background.png      2   barB.png
```

Comment: Thanks @RomanPekar, I fixed the typo. I added more discovery to my question. It seems the group by background is causing the issue. My goal is to get the results in the format listed above. That way the query returns exactly what I need for my use case. But I'm only assuming it's possible.

Comment: Turns out my sample data had a typo so my query never worked as intended. I edited my question. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you count distinct on rep_id you will get the number of rows where a unique combination occurred.

```
SELECT distinct array_agg(distinct r.rep_id) AS ids, count(distinct r.rep_id) AS ct, array[r.data->>'background', o->>'album', o->>'src'] as combination
FROM   reports r
  , json_array_elements(r.data->'objects') o
GROUP  BY r.data->>'background'
   , o->>'album'
   , o->>'src'
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
```

Result on first dataset:

```
ids     ct  combination
{1,2,3} 3   {background.png,1,fooA.png}
{1,3}   2   {background.png,2,barB.png}
{2}     1   {background.png,2,barC.png}
{4}     1   {backgroundA.png,1,fooA.png}
{4}     1   {backgroundA.png,3,barB.png}
```

Reult on second dataset:

```
ids     ct  combination
{1,2}   2   {background.png,2,barB.png}
{1}     1   {background.png,1,fooA.png}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This improves the counts but still doesn't return the results that I need. When an entry uses the the same files, albums and background, that is considered a combination. For instance, in the first dataset, 1 and 3 match, where 4 is a separate  combination because it has a different background. That's what I'm trying to get at. In the second dataset, 1 and 2 shouldn't be grouped at all. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877241/query-combinations-with-nested-array-of-records-in-json-datatype) for more.

Comment: Turns out my sample data had a typo so my query never worked as intended. I edited my question. I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand your goal.
The 
{1,2,3} 3   {background.png,1,fooA.png}
line is present because the 
{background.png,1,fooA.png}
combination is present in row 1,2 and 3