# how to match string in JSON array?

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2008, postgresql-9.3

I have a JSON column called data in a table called , The table looks something like this:

```
select * from data_table;

 id |           data   
----+------------------------
  1 | ["a","aa","aaa","aaaa"]
  2 | ["b","bb","bbb","bbbb"]
  3 | ["c","cc","ccc","cccc"]
```

What I would like to do is query the table for all data_table that matches the 'bbb' value in the data column?

I have tried things like this but to no avail:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_table 
WHERE data::text[] @> string_to_array('bbb',',') ;
```

Comment: As in any line that contains bbb regardless of what is around it you want it to return? So in the example above it would return the second line?

Comment: some versions of postgres seem to have json query built in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239225/how-to-search-sql-column-containing-json-array) which uses OPENJSON, much better than LIKE.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239225/how-to-search-sql-column-containing-json-array) which is much better than using LIKE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `%` wild card and a `LIKE` statement

```
SELECT * FROM data_table WHERE data LIKE '%"bbb%"';
```

Comment: thanks @Matt... but i want exact match, other rows may contain something like 'bbbbb' or 'abbb'.