# How to search SQL column containing JSON array

Tags: arrays, postgresql, t-sql, sql-server-2016, json-query

I have a SQL column that has a single JSON array:

```json
    {"names":["Joe","Fred","Sue"]}
```

Given a search string, how can I use SQL to search for a match in the names array?  I am using SQL 2016 and have looked at JSON_QUERY, but don't know how to search for a match on a JSON array.  Something like below would be nice.

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE JSON_QUERY(column, '$.names') = 'Joe'
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For doing a search in a JSON array, one needs to use `OPENJSON`

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Col NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('{"names":["Joe","Fred","Sue"]}')

SELECT * FROM @table 
WHERE 'Joe' IN ( SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(Col,'$.names'))
```

or as an alternative, one can use it with `CROSS APPLY`.

```
SELECT * FROM 
    @table 
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Col,'$.names')
WHERE value ='Joe'
```

Comment: SQL Server Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 4):

##### Postgres syntax

When you know the key that holds the data:

`SELECT column_name from table_name where column_name->>'key' LIKE '%QUERYSTRING%';`

When you don't know the key that holds the data:

`SELECT column_name from table_name where column_name::text LIKE '%QUERYSTRING%';`

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add to the existing answers a simple solution how you can check if array inside json contains a value:

```
DECLARE @Json NVARCHAR(max) = '{"names":["Joe","Fred","Sue"]}'
IF EXISTS (SELECT value FROM OPENJSON(@Json,'$.names') WHERE value = 'Joe')
    PRINT 'Array contains "Joe"'
ELSE
    PRINT 'Array does not contain "Joe"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a match on a JSON array via below query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(COLUMN, "$.names") AS NAME
FROM TABLE JSON_EXTRACT(COLUMN, "$.names") != ""
```

Replace the TABLE with your table name and COLUMN with the column name in the table.
the key I have mentioned name as it was there in your question.

Answer (score -1):

It's very simple , can be easily done using JSON_CONTAINS() function.

```
SELECT * FROM  table
where  JSON_CONTAINS(column, 'joe','$.name');
```

Comment: MySQL Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: This only works for MySQL, the question is about SQL 2016.

Comment: Finally, something that is simple and working!