# Find Data in Structured JSON

Tags: php, mysql

I have JSON from maxmind in my table column with datatype varcher(1000)

```
[{"confidence":99,"iso_code":"NJ","geoname_id":5101760,"names":{"en":"New Jersey","es":"Nueva Jersey","fr":"New Jersey","ja":"\u30cb\u30e5\u30fc\u30b8\u30e3\u30fc\u30b8\u30fc\u5dde","pt-BR":"Nova J\u00e9rsia","ru":"\u041d\u044c\u044e-\u0414\u0436\u0435\u0440\u0441\u0438","zh-CN":"\u65b0\u6cfd\u897f\u5dde"}}]
```

how do I search and out put all iso_code who have NJ NY
I have array of iso codes

without the JSON I would have done as follow

```
select geotbl.id,geotbl.email from geotbl where  iso_code IN ('NY','NJ')
```

not all rows have JSON text some are null or empty

here is dbfiddle : [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e74b59c9c93199ece5ac7e438e7deb6f)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search SQL column containing JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239225/how-to-search-sql-column-containing-json-array)

Comment: `WHERE geotbl.jsoncolumn->>"$.iso_code IN ('NY','NJ')`

Comment: Can you run `SELECT VERSION();` and report what it returns?

Comment: @Akina that will not work, because it is anrray

Comment: @BillKarwin
SELECT VERSION(); 
8.0.23

Comment: @nbk No problems, `"$[0].iso_code" `

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_extract to get the shortcut for Nwe Jersey

you can of course use IN clause as well instead of the eqal

> ```
> CREATE table js (val JSON)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO js VALUEs ('[{"confidence":99,"iso_code":"NJ","geoname_id":5101760,"names":{"en":"New Jersey","es":"Nueva Jersey","fr":"New Jersey","ja":"\u30cb\u30e5\u30fc\u30b8\u30e3\u30fc\u30b8\u30fc\u5dde","pt-BR":"Nova J\u00e9rsia","ru":"\u041d\u044c\u044e-\u0414\u0436\u0435\u0440\u0441\u0438","zh-CN":"\u65b0\u6cfd\u897f\u5dde"}}]
> ')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 1 FROM js WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(val, "$[*].iso_code") = 'NJ'
> ```
>
> ```
> |  1 |
> | -: |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>
> JSON_EXTRACT(val, "$[*].iso_code")  from js
> ```
>
> ```
> | JSON_EXTRACT(val, "$[*].iso_code") |
> | :--------------------------------- |
> | ["NJ"]                             |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ecfa49c499baf3368d2c0d0cd8034d7)*

I don't know why MySQL doesn't like your JSON, jsonlint had no problems with it, but you can always use string functions, if you don't can't use json datatype

> ```
> CREATE table js (val varchar(1000))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO js VALUEs ('[{"confidence":99,"iso_code":"NJ","geoname_id":5101760,"names":{"en":"New Jersey","es":"Nueva Jersey","fr":"New Jersey","ja":"\u30cb\u30e5\u30fc\u30b8\u30e3\u30fc\u30b8\u30fc\u5dde","pt-BR":"Nova J\u00e9rsia","ru":"\u041d\u044c\u044e-\u0414\u0436\u0435\u0440\u0441\u0438","zh-CN":"\u65b0\u6cfd\u897f\u5dde"}}]
> ')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO js VALUEs ('')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM js WHERE REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(vaL,LOCATE('"iso_code":"',val) + 11),',',1),'"','') IN ('NJ','NI')
> ```
>
> ```
> | val                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | [{"confidence":99,"iso_code":"NJ","geoname_id":5101760,"names":{"en":"New Jersey","es":"Nueva Jersey","fr":"New Jersey","ja":"u30cbu30e5u30fcu30b8u30e3u30fcu30b8u30fcu5dde","pt-BR":"Nova Ju00e9rsia","ru":"u041du044cu044e-u0414u0436u0435u0440u0441u0438","zh-CN":"u65b0u6cfdu897fu5dde"}}]<br> |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>  REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(vaL,LOCATE('"iso_code":"',val) + 11),',',1),'"','')  from js
> ```
>
> ```
> | REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(vaL,LOCATE('"iso_code":"',val) + 11),',',1),'"','') |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ |
> | NJ                                                                                    |
> |                                                                                       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=54b852a5fa52034ee826cfdc57914743)*

Comment: SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(subdivisions, "$[*].iso_code")  from geo_test_datas;
get error
Error Code: 3141. Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_extract: "The document is empty." at position 0.

Comment: you must provide a dbfiddle, so i can check that, as you see in principle this works

Comment: not all columns have JSON text some are null or empty , thats why the error , also the datatype of column in varchar(1000) not JSON

Comment: here is the dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e74b59c9c93199ece5ac7e438e7deb6f

Comment: i can't see why, so use string functions