# AR Query for jsonb attribute column

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, jsonb

I'm using Postgres for my db, and I have a column in my Auction model as a jsonb column. I want to create a query that searches the Auction's json column to see whether a user's name OR email exists in any Auction instance's json column.

Right now I have `@auctions = Auction.where('invitees @> ?', {current_user.name.downcase => current_user.email.downcase}.to_json)`, but that only brings back exact `key => value` matches I want to know whether the name OR the email exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're using the `@>` operator. The description for it is this:

   > “Does the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries
   >   at the top level?”

   You probably want the `?` operator if you want to return a row when the key (name in your case) matches.
2. There's not a good way to search for values only in a JSON column ([see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29611533/203130)), but you could check if the key exists alone or the key and value match exists.
3. The same ActiveRecord methods and chaining apply as when using non-JSON columns, namely `where` and `where(…).or(where(…))`:

   ```
   class Auction
     def self.by_invitee(user)
       name = user.name.downcase
       json = { name => user.email } # note: you should be downcasing emails anyways
       where('invitee ? :name', name: name).or(
         where('invitee @> :json', json: json)
       )
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a temporary patch until I add an `Invite` model, but casting the invitee column to text I can search the columns. Like so

```
SELECT * FROM auctions
WHERE data::text LIKE "%#{string I'm searching for}%"
```

So, AR:

```
Auction.where('data::text LIKE ?', "%#{string I'm searching for}%")
```

Comment: FWIW, this is going to be really slow compared to the JSONB lookups, especially since you're casting every row in that table to text, then searching it without any indexing.