# Sum all of the items in a JSONB array field

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

If my table is setup like:

```
indicators:
  id: 56789,
  funding (JSONB): [
    {
      amount: 345678
    },
    {
      amount: 7899
    }
  ]
```

I can successfully sum the first amounts on every record with:

Rails — `Indicator.sum("(funding->0->>'amount')::float")`

SQL — `SELECT SUM((funding->0->>'amount')::float) FROM "indicators"`

**How would you query a sum of all of the `amounts` (not just the 0 index items)?**

Running Rails 5 & Postgres 9.5.4.

*Note:* This post is similar to [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) - but I'm looking for a way to iterate over each of the array elements to sum them (as opposed to calling them directly by an index number).

**Update...**
Thanks to @klin's answer below, I was able to put together the Rails version that gave me the aggregate total:

```
Indicator.joins("cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(funding)").sum("(value->>'amount')::float")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

```
select sum((value->>'amount')::float)
from indicators
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(funding)
```