# Difference between JSON and JSONB in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, sqldatatypes, jsonb

What's difference between JSON and JSONB data type in PosgresSQL?

1. When should be used specific one?
2. What's benefits or disadvantages with respect to other?

Comment: Another overview: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761

Comment: The data types json and jsonb , as defined by the PostgreSQL documentation,are almost identical; the key difference is that json data is stored as an exact copy of the JSON input text, whereas jsonb stores data in a decomposed binary form; that is, not as an ASCII/UTF-8 string, but as binary code.

Comment: It's already answered somewhere else but the title of this entry is better to find my solution!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is explain:
https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/07/14/choosing-nosql-hstore-json-jsonb/

> In most cases JSONB is likely what you want when looking for a NoSQL,
> schema-less, datatype. Hstore and JSON can have their place as well
> but it’s less common. More broadly, JSONB isn’t always a fit in every
> data model. Where you can normalize there are benefits, but if you do
> have a schema that has a large number of optional columns (such as
> with event data) or the schema differs based on tenant id then JSONB
> can be a great fit. In general you want:
>
> - JSONB - In most cases
> - JSON - If you’re just processing logs, don’t often need to query, and use as more of an audit trail
> - hstore - Can work fine for text based key-value looks, but in general JSONB can still work great here

Answer (score 106):

`json` is basically a blob that stores JSON data in raw format, preserving even insignificant things such as whitespace, the order of keys in objects, or even duplicate keys in objects. It does offer the ability to do some basic JSON operations such as extracting the value associated with some key in an object, albeit it is slow at that since it has to parse the JSON blob every time. It also validates every value to check that it is valid JSON. `jsonb` on the other hand stores JSON data in a custom format that is optimized for certain operations such as extracting the value associated with some key in an object (i.e. it will not reparse JSON, it will not search linearly). Additionally, `jsonb` supports more operations, just as concatenation of objects or setting a value deep inside an object.

In general, I use `json` only if I know that I will not do any JSON operations or only do them occasionally. For all other cases I use `jsonb`. Note that for the former case, `text` it is also a perfectly valid option, especially if you are not interested in the validation that `json` does (e.g. because you trust the source of the data).