# PostgreSQL JSONB drawbacks and differences

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I want to use JSONB but then I have read this:

```
JSON
The JSON data type works better than JSONB when:

You have to perform a lot of INSERT operations
You do not expect to perform complex queries on your JSON data
You need to preserve the original JSON data indentation and format
```

So in my case I have a lot of insert operations but also a lot of reads/updates.

So what to use now? It is an e-commerce application.

And has JSONB any drawbacks or it is not good for e-commerce structure?

Comment: "Lots of inserts" refers to huge imports with millions of rows, where storing the text as it is received is simpler and more performant than parsing it into a better data structure. You do not have that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON vs JSONB Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820299/json-vs-jsonb-postgresql)

Comment: "*I have read this*" - where? Please [edit] your question to add a link

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "lots of updates". Do you replace the whole JSON with a different JSON?

Comment: "a lot" is not a number and it's unclear what kind of (virtual) hardware you're using. 1000 transactions per second used to be a lot for a single database, nowadays it's normal to this kind of performance. On AWS, Azure and other cloud environments you're just a few clicks away from much higher IOPS anyway. Besides this, you know your data, you can setup a test environment and test the different datatypes for your specific workload.

Comment: @FrankHeikens but which would you prefer ? I have also take care of MVCC

Comment: My personal preference is jsonb, it matches my requirements slightly better then json. But that's just me, I don't know your requirements.