# PostgreSQL create index in JSON array element

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.5, and I want to create an index for multiple fields of a JSON object. I'm showing two examples, the first one is working and I'm stuck on the second one.

- ### Example 1 - working

For the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE product(id SERIAL, description JSONB);

INSERT INTO product(id, description) VALUES(1, '{"category":"shoes","name":"red women shoes","brand":"nike"}');
INSERT INTO product(id, description) VALUES(2, '{"category":"shoes","name":"women heels shoes","brand":"red valentino"}');

CREATE INDEX "product_description_idx" ON product USING GIN(to_tsvector('english', (description->>'name') || ' ' || (description->>'category')));

SELECT * from product WHERE to_tsvector('english', (description->>'name') || ' ' || (description->>'category')) @@ to_tsquery('shoes & red');
```

I got as output only the product **id** = 1, with is correct.

- ### Example 2 - here is where I'm stuck

For the same table, but this time the description is an array of objects:

```
CREATE TABLE product(id SERIAL, description JSONB);

INSERT INTO product(id, description) VALUES(1, '[{"category":"shoes","name":"red women shoes","brand":"nike"}, {"category":"hat","name":"white hat","brand":"nike"}]');
INSERT INTO product(id, description) VALUES(2, '[{"category":"shoes","name":"women heels shoes","brand":"red valentino"}, {"category":"dress","name":"maxi dress","brand":"red valentino"}]');
```

How can I create an index, like in Example 1, using the **name** and **description** of all objects of the JSON array?

Note: I just want to create the index with these two fields, **name** and **description**, because if the field **brand** is part of the index as well, the product **id** = 2 will be returned as a result and that should not happen.

I've searched for similar questions, like [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404055/index-for-finding-an-element-in-a-json-array/18405706#18405706) and [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I couldn't figure out a solution.

Thanks,
Sérgio

Comment: hi, did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

For all JSON elements and for JSON arrays recommended use this syntax:

```
CREATE INDEX "product_description_gin_idx" ON product USING gin (description jsonb_path_ops)
```