# ActiveModel jsonb attribute class different on localhost vs production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a Rails 5.0.2 app running PostgreSQL 9.6 on Heroku with the following model:

```
create_table "stories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "title",                     default: "",    null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.boolean  "image_processing"
  t.jsonb    "image_json"
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

In my app, I assume that `image_json` is a `Hash`. So when I call `Story.last.image_json.class`, I expect the output to always be `Hash`, which holds true in my development environment. When I run the same command on production (Heroku), the output is not `Hash`, but rather `String`. How is this possible?

On localhost:

```
Story.last.image_json.class
=> Hash
```

On production:

```
Story.last.image_json.class
=> String
```

At first I thought that perhaps it was because I was running a slightly older version of Postgres in development (9.4) than on production, but upgrading both Postgres installs to 9.6 had no effect.

I've temporarily solved the issue by simply checking the class of `image_json` in my code before operating on it, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: Did you check that both heroku production and development database field is jsonb type, and what is the data type of Story.image_json ? Thanks

Comment: They're both `jsonb`, I checked.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know. I have seen this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype#10560761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Rails 5.0.2 problem - [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/28285)

Comment: Good find, thanks! Hopefully they release this as a patch soon. Suppose I could also just point to the master branch...