# Querying json field by array index and object property

Tags: postgresql

I have a column like:

```
[
   {
      "type":"menu",
      "prompt": {
            "type":"say",
            "message":"This is a menu. Pick option 1 or 2."
      }
   }
]
```

The first tier object could contain a variety of types and any number of types.  My objective (for automated testing, not production, so it can be inefficient) is to find a record with any `column.*.type = menu`.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22687653/197606 I understand I can provide a numeric index, but running the query `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'my_column'->0->'type' = 'menu'` throws the error:

```
ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown -> integer
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'my_column'->0->'type' =...
                                                       ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: operator is not unique: unknown -> integer
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

While specifying a numeric index of `0` would work for this specific use case and is an acceptable answer, I'd prefer an approach that isn't picky about the column index.

Comment: Do you need this: `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column->0->>'type' = 'menu'`  ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze Bingo, that was it!

Comment: @OtoShavadze Can you post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Ok, I posted it as an answer ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column->0->>'type' = 'menu'
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not allow to look in json array. Your solution might be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM  jsonb_array_elements(my_column) AS j
      WHERE j->>'type' = 'menu'
)
```