# postgresql json array query

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I tried to query my json array using the example here: [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

They use the example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   json_array_elements(
  '[{"name": "Toby", "occupation": "Software Engineer"},
    {"name": "Zaphod", "occupation": "Galactic President"} ]'
  ) AS elem
WHERE elem->>'name' = 'Toby';
```

But my Json array looks more like this (if using the example):

```
    {
    "people": [{
            "name": "Toby",
        "occupation": "Software Engineer"
    },
    {
        "name": "Zaphod",
        "occupation": "Galactic President"
    }
    ]
}
```

But I get an error: ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array

Is my Json "array" not really an array? I have to use this Json string because it's contained in a database, so I would have to tell them to fix it if it's not an array.
Or, is there another way to query it?

I read documentation but nothing worked, kept getting errors.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The json array has a key `people` so use `my_json->'people'` in the function:

```
with my_table(my_json) as (
values(
'{
    "people": [
        {
            "name": "Toby",
            "occupation": "Software Engineer"
        },
        {
            "name": "Zaphod",
            "occupation": "Galactic President"
        }
    ]
}'::json)
)
select t.*
from my_table t
cross join json_array_elements(my_json->'people') elem
where elem->>'name' = 'Toby';
```

---

The function `json_array_elements()` unnests the json array and generates all its elements as rows:

```
select elem->>'name' as name, elem->>'occupation' as occupation
from my_table
cross join json_array_elements(my_json->'people') elem

  name  |     occupation     
--------+--------------------
 Toby   | Software Engineer
 Zaphod | Galactic President
(2 rows)
```

If you are interested in Toby's occupation:

```
select elem->>'occupation' as occupation
from my_table
cross join json_array_elements(my_json->'people') elem
where elem->>'name' = 'Toby'

    occupation     
-------------------
 Software Engineer
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I had some bad data in other rows, so I had to choose only a "good" row. Now I have another question: how can I select only the "occupation" for example? Where you say select t.* I only want the "occupation". I tried t.my_json -> 'occupation' and it didn't work. The results show ?column? and null data which it isn't null in my row.

Comment: You are awesome B-)

Comment: I've seen several people try to explain how to do this and you have given the most elegant solution on stack. Thank you sir.