# Rails search thru JSON attribute

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have a `Foo` model. It has keywords.

```
create_table "foos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.json "keywords"
end
```

The keywords are stored as an array: `["quick", "brown", "fox"]`

I was wondering how to choose foos with one of the keywords being `"fox"`.

I was watching this [video](https://youtu.be/I6D1HWf6isk?t=15m6s) and it said to use something like `WHERE details -> 'tags' ? 'techie'`

But this only works because `details` in their example is a hash

```
{
  "contacts": [...],
  "tags": [...]
}
```

I'm not digging through a hash, I just want to search through an array. I've tried this:

```
Foo.where("keywords -> 'fox'")
```

but it raises

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type json
LINE 1: SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE (keywords -> 'fox') LIM...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE (keywords -> 'fox') LIMIT $1
```

A [tutorial](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails) suggests to use `?| array[:keys]` like so:

```
Foo.where('keywords ?| array[:keys]', keys: ['brown', 'fox'])
```

But I get the same kind of error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ?| text[]
LINE 1: SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE (keywords ?| array['fox...
                                                       ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT  "foos".* FROM "foos" WHERE (keywords ?| array['fox','quick']) LIMIT $1
```

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `JSONB` data type instead of `JSON`.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)
is a good topic.

Compare

```
> select '["a", "fox", "c"]'::jsonb ?| array['fox','quick'] as exists;

 exists
--------
 t
(1 row)
```

to

```
> select '["a", "fox", "c"]'::json ?| array['fox','quick'] as exists;

ERROR:  operator does not exist: json ?| text[]
LINE 1: select '["a", "fox", "c"]'::json ?| array['fox','quick'] as ...
```

P.S. And then you have an option to index your `keywords` column.

Comment: Thanks! `Foo.where("keywords::jsonb ?| array['fox', 'quick']")` worked! I get the correct results

Comment: It would be better to make migration and change `keywords` type from `json` to `jsonb`. The query will go faster than type cast `keywords::jsonb ?| ...`