# Postgres ad nested json

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to parse a field from a nested JSON using postgresql. The form of a JSON has the following form:

```
{"Field_1": {"Field_2": {"Field_3": "value_1": "xxx"}}}
```

I have read the question [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype)
 and I have searched the proposed links, but I have not found anything to work.

```
{"Field_1": {"Field_2": {"Field_3": "value_1": "xxx"}}}
```

I want to parse the `xxx` of `value_1`.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON have incorrect syntax, this is correct one:

```
{"Field_1": {"Field_2": {"Field_3": {"value_1": "xxx"}}}}
```

Then  you can:

```
select j->'Field_1'->'Field_2'->'Field_3'->'value_1' from (
    select '{"Field_1": {"Field_2": {"Field_3": {"value_1": "xxx"}}}}'::jsonb as j
) t
```