# Returning JSON arrary with particular property using Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, json-patch

I have a JSONB data stored in a column called `data` in table `nftdata`. Inside this JSON data (as shown below) there is a JSON array at `result.data.items`. This is an array of 2400 JSON objects but I have shown two here as an example:

```json
{
    "api_version": "0.1",
    "result": {
        "api_code": 200,
        "api_response": "Success",
        "data": {
            "collection": "XXX NFT",
            "ranking_url": "https://nft",
            "twitter": "https://twitter.com/nft/",
            "discord": "https://discord.com/invite/",
            "website": "https://nft.io/",
            "description": "2",
            "logo": "https://icons/f245c3aea5e279691f5f460d9d499afe.jpg",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": 2414,
                    "link": "/2414",
                    "mint": "FHAJS21yJBtYDuix1x7woZPUo",
                    "name": "NFT #2414",
                    "description": "-",
                    "image": "https://arweave.net/mKbawCJP4dX9_IZg",
                    "attributes": ["Deleted to shorten post"],
                    "rank": 1,
                    "rank_algo": "h",
                    "all_ranks": {
                        "is": 1,
                        "trait_normalized": 1,
                        "statistical_rarity": 1876
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 198,
                    "link": "/198",
                    "mint": "EiGbBm7CsB8ZeZF5Hg",
                    "name": "NFT #198",
                    "description": "-",
                    "image": "https://arweave.net/fAVzxoqcsracjf",
                    "attributes": ["Deleted to shorten post"],
                    "rank": 2,
                    "rank_algo": "h",
                    "all_ranks": {
                        "is": 2,
                        "trait_normalized": 2,
                        "statistical_rarity": 2246
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The table this data is in is held like this:

| collection_ID (text) | data (jsonb) |
| --- | --- |
| collection1 | JSONB data blob (as above) |
| collection2 | JSONB data blob (as above) |

I would like to use a Postgres query to first find the right table row based on its primary key (e.g. `collection1`), then search through the JSON in the data column of that particular table row for one of the 2400 objects (stored at `result.data.items`) with a particular ID (in nodejs it would be something like `result.data.items[i].id`) and if found, return the particular 'items' object (e.g. `result.data.items[i]`).

For example, I would like to search `collection1` for id `2414` and return:

```json
{
 "id": 2414,
 "link": "/2414",
 "mint": "FHAJS21yJBtYDuix1x7woZPUo",
 "name": "NFT #2414",
 "description": "-",
 "image": "https://arweave.net/mKbawCJP4dX9_IZg",
 "attributes": [ 'Deleted to shorten post'
],
 "rank": 1,
 "rank_algo": "h",
 "all_ranks": {
     "is": 1,
     "trait_normalized": 1,
     "statistical_rarity": 1876
     }
}
```

Edit: thanks for the answer below which solved the problem. For future readers I implemented the query in nodejs like this:

```
//pass nftid as string and collectionstring (collection_ID) as string into function

var querystring = "SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(data #> '{result,data,items}', '$[*] ? (@.id == " + nftid + " || @.id == \"" + nftid + "\")') AS result FROM howraredata WHERE  collection_id = '" + collectionstring + "' "

pgclient.query(querystring, (err, res) => {
      if (err) throw err
      //do stuff
      })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [SQL/JSON path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) with the function [`jsonb_path_query_first()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) this gets **remarkably simple**:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.result.data.items[*] ? (@.id == 2414)')
FROM   nftdata
WHERE  collection_id = 'collection1';
```

Produces the desired result.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=b2ccb7ef58cef832963b542cb863159d)*

Though, understanding SQL/JSON path functionality may not be as simple. It was added to **Postgres 12**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)

> To refer to the JSON data to be queried (the context item), use the
> `$` sign in the path expression. It can be followed by one or more
> [**accessor operators**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#TYPE-JSONPATH-ACCESSORS), which go down the JSON structure level by
> level to retrieve the content of context item. Each operator that
> follows deals with the result of the previous evaluation step.

So:

`$.result.data.items[*]` ... retrieve nested array as per your definition

> When defining a path, you can also use one or more filter expressions
> that work similarly to the `WHERE` clause in SQL. A filter expression
> begins with a question mark and provides a condition in parentheses:
>
> `? (condition)`

`? (@.id == 2414)')`  ... filter the array element that has the top level key "id" with value *2414*.

Related:

- [How to query nested unamed jsonb objects and order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313836/3684)
- [How to sum the values ​of a json column filtered with regex?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/274276/3684)

Comment: I have use realised that some of the databases are strong the id as integer and some as strings. Is there a way to modify the query to find the id as either?

Comment: I was able to get it with (@.id == 2414 || @.id == "2414")

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in JSON operator and functions for that. You gave a picture instead of text, thus I am giving a simple sample based on that picture but with only two columns:

```
select *
from jsonb_to_recordset('{
  "result": {
    "data": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1234,
          "description": "d1"
        },
        {
          "id": 1235,
          "description": "d2"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'::jsonb #> '{result, data, items}') as x(id int, description text);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6836ac10389cf7697a4566dc7ceb358b)

EDIT: As per new data in your question, you can use jsonb_array_elements (create GIN index if you haven't already did):

```
select item
from nftdata nd,
     jsonb_array_elements(nd.data #> '{result, data, items}') item
where (item->>'id')::int = 2414;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2ab0e3d84ea09b3ddae6bfd52cda2ddc)

EDIT: When you are sure that the Id is int:

```
select item
from nftdata nd,
     jsonb_array_elements(nd.data #> '{result, data, items}') item
where item->>'id' = '2414';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I realise I perhaps wasn't clear enough with my initial post, so have edited it above. Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: @Laniakea, edited for your case.

Comment: @Laniakea, I am not sure if you already know that you are searching for collection1. I got that as if you were searching for the item with id = 2414. It should be easier to add collection_id = 'collection1' to where.

Comment: Thanks. Your example is a useful reference as it is different. I have also just realised that sometimes the id is stored as an integer and sometimes as a string! Is there a way to modify the query to find both?

Comment: @Laniakea, edited to show that. Simply you remove casting to int and pass as '2414'.