# How to check if a value exists in any key of a json object?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I have a `jsonb` column it has many keys. If any key has a particular value which I am looking for it should return true.

As keys doen't matter for my requirement, my idea is to check against an array of extracted values. So is there a way to get all the values of a `jsonb` into an array?

```
if json_array_length(tms_hlpr_usr_has_authority_fr_srvc_requests(usr_id_,org_id_)) > 0 then
        _extra_where = _extra_where || 
            ' and ' || quote_literal(usr_id_) || '  =  any(srvc_req.form_data->>[how to check all keys here]) and srvc_req.is_deleted is not true ';
end if;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are building an SQL command to dynamically execute with `EXECUTE` in a Postgres function.

To check whether any top-level key has the given value, the most elegant way will be an [SQL/JSON path expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH). This can be supported with an index and should be decently fast. No need to expensively extract all values into an array first.

Basic example to check for the value `2`:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_exists(jsonb '{"a":1, "b":2}', '$.* ? (@ == 2)');
```

To pass in your variable `usr_id_` of unknown type (in place of the numeric value `2` of the basic example):

```
SELECT jsonb_path_exists(jsonb '{"a":1, "b":2}'
                       , '$.* ? (@ == $usr_id)'
                       , jsonb_build_object('usr_id', 1));
```

Concatenating the `WHERE` clause in your PL/pgSQL code block can look like this:

```sql
IF json_array_length(tms_hlpr_usr_has_authority_fr_srvc_requests(usr_id_,org_id_)) > 0 THEN
   _extra_where = _extra_where
           || $j$ AND jsonb_path_exists(srvc_req.form_data, '$.* ? (@ == $usr_id)', $1) AND srvc_req.is_deleted IS NOT TRUE $j$;
END IF;
```

Using dollar-quoting to allow for nested single quotes. See:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)

Supply the value for the parameter symbol `$1` in a `USING` clause to the `EXECUTE` command. Like:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM srvc_req ' || _extra_where
USING   jsonb_build_object('usr_id', usr_id_);  -- $1 !
```

Related:

- [Returning JSON arrary with particular property using Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295082/returning-json-arrary-with-particular-property-using-postgres/73297778#73297778)

(This would be much easier to demonstrate if you had provided your actual minimal function.)