# Postgresql Query JsonB

Tags: postgresql

I have this query and I don't know what is wrong ?

From which I want to extract the Name information where the name of the products is and the quantities that each product brings.
How should I modify the query to make it work?

```
SELECT o.id,
       d->>'name' AS "Unidades"
FROM rtdm_order o
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT value->>'name'
    FROM jsonb::->> o.integration_raw_data->>'details' AS value
) AS d
WHERE o.restaurant_id = '1'
AND created_timestamp BETWEEN '2023-09-11' AND '2023-09-23'
AND d->>'name' IS NOT NULL;
```

Error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "::"
LINE 6:     FROM jsonb::->> o.integration_raw_data->>'details' AS va...
                      ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 125
```

Json

```
{
    "origin": "WEB",
    "restaurantId": 37,
    "notes": "",
    "restaurantName": "xxxxx",
    "utm": {
        "utm_campaign": null,
        "utm_content": null,
        "utm_medium": "xxxx",
        "utm_source": "xxxxl",
        "utm_term": null
    },
    "registeredDate": "2023-09-13 19:08:47.754",
    "id": 5226408,
    "user": {
        "lastName": "xxxxxe",
        "isNew": false,
        "id": 180051,
        "firstName": "xxxxa ",
        "email": "xxxxxxxx"
    },
    "address": {
        "area": "",
        "tel": "5491123573490",
        "extra": "",
        "crossStreets": "",
        "notes": "",
        "cel": "91123573490",
        "manual": false,
        "zipCode": "",
        "phone": "xxxxx / xxxxx",
        "street": "",
        "location": null,
        "streetNumber": "",
        "city": null,
        "streetName": ""
    },
    "deliveryDate": "2023-09-13 20:45:00.000",
    "payment": {
        "paymentAmount": 18000,
        "currencyCode": "ARS",
        "currencySymbol": "$",
        "shipping": 0,
        "notes": "",
        "online": false,
        "total": 17810,
        "subTotal": 17810,
        "method": "Efectivo"
    },
    "pickUp": true,
    "details": [
        {
            "categoryName": "Rolls",
            "optionsGroups": [
                {
                    "name": "Tama\u00f1o",
                    "modifiesBasePrice": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "5 unidades",
                            "price": 0,
                            "externalName": "",
                            "externalId": "2",
                            "id": 395660,
                            "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "externalId": "",
                    "sortOrder": 1,
                    "basePrice": 0,
                    "id": 108252
                }
            ],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2250,
            "externalName": "New York",
            "externalId": "2",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2250,
            "id": 328077,
            "name": "New York"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rolls",
            "optionsGroups": [
                {
                    "name": "Tama\u00f1o",
                    "modifiesBasePrice": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "5 unidades",
                            "price": 0,
                            "externalName": "",
                            "externalId": "11",
                            "id": 395682,
                            "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "externalId": "",
                    "sortOrder": 1,
                    "basePrice": 0,
                    "id": 108263
                }
            ],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2250,
            "externalName": "Feel",
            "externalId": "6",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2250,
            "id": 328182,
            "name": "Feel"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rolls especiales",
            "optionsGroups": [
                {
                    "name": "Tama\u00f1o",
                    "modifiesBasePrice": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "5 unidades",
                            "price": 0,
                            "externalName": "",
                            "externalId": "19",
                            "id": 395692,
                            "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "externalId": "",
                    "sortOrder": 1,
                    "basePrice": 0,
                    "id": 108268
                }
            ],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2450,
            "externalName": "Ibiza",
            "externalId": "19",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2450,
            "id": 328093,
            "name": "Ibiza"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Sashimis",
            "optionsGroups": [],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2700,
            "externalName": "Sashimi maracuy\u00e1 (5u)",
            "externalId": "71",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2700,
            "id": 328134,
            "name": "Sashimi maracuy\u00e1 (5u)"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rolls especiales",
            "optionsGroups": [
                {
                    "name": "Tama\u00f1o",
                    "modifiesBasePrice": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "5 unidades",
                            "price": 0,
                            "externalName": "",
                            "externalId": "8020",
                            "id": 395788,
                            "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "externalId": "",
                    "sortOrder": 1,
                    "basePrice": 0,
                    "id": 108315
                }
            ],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2450,
            "externalName": "",
            "externalId": "299",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2450,
            "id": 328097,
            "name": "Tari Tari Roll - NUEVO!"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Rolls especiales",
            "optionsGroups": [
                {
                    "name": "Tama\u00f1o",
                    "modifiesBasePrice": true,
                    "options": [
                        {
                            "name": "5 unidades",
                            "price": 0,
                            "externalName": "",
                            "externalId": "23",
                            "id": 395730,
                            "quantity": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "externalId": "",
                    "sortOrder": 1,
                    "basePrice": 0,
                    "id": 108287
                }
            ],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2450,
            "externalName": "Bs. As. con Langostino",
            "externalId": "23",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2450,
            "id": 328111,
            "name": "Bs. As. con Langostino"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Niguiris",
            "optionsGroups": [],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 530,
            "externalName": "",
            "externalId": "50",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 2,
            "subtotal": 1060,
            "id": 328117,
            "name": "Niguiri salm\u00f3n"
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "Niguiris",
            "optionsGroups": [],
            "ingredients": [],
            "price": 2200,
            "externalName": "Niguiri Lima (4u)",
            "externalId": "135",
            "notes": "",
            "quantity": 1,
            "subtotal": 2200,
            "id": 328127,
            "name": "Niguiri Lima (4u)"
        }
    ]
}
```

From which I want to extract the Name information where the name of the products is and the quantities that each product brings.
How should I modify the query to make it work?

Comment: Is this duplicate with: [How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype) ?

Comment: SELECT O.ID "VCloudId",O.INTEGRATION_RAW_DATA "jsondata",
 (O.INTEGRATION_RAW_DATA::JSON->'details'->0->'optionsGroups'->0->'options'->0->>'name') AS "Unit"
  from rtdm_order O
 where o.integration_raw_data ILIKE '%Vegetarian roll%'
        AND O.restaurant_id = 1 
        AND O.ORIGIN_ID = 3 
        AND O.INTEGRATION_ORIGIN_ID = 1
       and O.CREATED_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2023-09-10' AND '2023-09-26';
With this query I get almost to what I'm looking for, but in some json where I should extract the quantities they are null, could it be that they are like this?

Comment: You should not post code in a comment, Please use [edit] to add it to your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm new :=)

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work:

```
select 
   x2->'id' as id,
   x2->'name' as name,
   x2->'quantity' as quantity
from (
   select jsonb_array_elements(x1) as x2
   from (
      select 
         t->'details' as x1
      from t) x
      ) y
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/qhx11zaE)

output:

| id | name | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 328077 | "New York" | 1 |
| 328182 | "Feel" | 1 |
| 328093 | "Ibiza" | 1 |
| 328134 | "Sashimi maracuyá (5u)" | 1 |
| 328097 | "Tari Tari Roll - NUEVO!" | 1 |
| 328111 | "Bs. As. con Langostino" | 1 |
| 328117 | "Niguiri salmón" | 2 |
| 328127 | "Niguiri Lima (4u)" | 1 |

This query is following the step-by-step procedure.

First do

```
SELECT t->'details' as x1 FROM t`
```

Then do:

```
select jsonb_array_elements(x1) as x2
   from (
      select 
         t->'details' as x1
      from t) x
```

After that step 3 completed the journey.

(The steps are also present in the DBFIDDLE)

Unfortunately you did not specify expected output, so I cannot check If you thing this is correct.